# How do I make the program fail? Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, backtracking

I have a recursive program with this structure:

```
P1(I,SOL):-
  'does something',
  P(I,[I],SOL).

P1(A,B,SOL):-
  'does something',
   P2(A1,B1,B2,SOL).

P2(A,_,_,SOL):-
  goal(A).

P2(A,B,C,D):-
  'does something',
   MARK,
  'does something',
  P2(A1,B1,B2,SOL).
```

At `MARK` I have a condition (`C<Limit`).
The problem is when that condition fails, the program doesn´t fail. I think it backtracks and keeps running not going anywhere but consuming a lot of memory, How do I make the program fail if the condition is not met?

Comment: Try using a cut - `!`.

Comment: see also `fail/0` that is often used with cut for the specific scenario you have outlined